# Identification of AES portion code in binary

Tags: ida, disassembly, binary-analysis, encryption, cryptography

I want to locate AES code portion in binary after reverse engineering. I have tried to locate manually and using plugin `findcrypt2` but I was not successful. Kindly show me a direction so that I can work on this topic.

I am using Windows 10 operating system. The application I am reversing is AESCrypt and 7-zip. The Tool I am using for disassembly is IDA pro and also used findcrypt2 plugin but it did not work well. I have looked for the S-box and used the plugin to detect that specific area but I have no clue where to look

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: That's a bit of a broad question. I suggest you mention (either by tag or in the body) the architecture ("CPU") as well as the environment ("OS") and what exactly you have been trying.

Comment: Sir I am using Windows 10 operating system. The application I am reversing is AESCrypt and 7-zip. The Tool I am using for disassembly is IDA pro and also used findcrypt2 plugin but it did not work well. I have looked for the S-box and used the plugin to detect that specific area but I have no clue where to look.

Answer (score 5):

The best way to locate AES in a binary blob would be to locate first the [AES S-box](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rijndael_S-box). It is specifically designed for AES and recommended by the NIST, so a standard AES must include it. Moreover, they are quite unique and easily found through a simple pattern recognition. Here is the value of such S-box:

```
unsigned char s[256] = 
{
  0x63, 0x7C, 0x77, 0x7B, 0xF2, 0x6B, 0x6F, 0xC5, 0x30, 0x01, 0x67, 0x2B, 0xFE,
  0xD7, 0xAB, 0x76, 0xCA, 0x82, 0xC9, 0x7D, 0xFA, 0x59, 0x47, 0xF0, 0xAD, 0xD4,
  0xA2, 0xAF, 0x9C, 0xA4, 0x72, 0xC0, 0xB7, 0xFD, 0x93, 0x26, 0x36, 0x3F, 0xF7,
  0xCC, 0x34, 0xA5, 0xE5, 0xF1, 0x71, 0xD8, 0x31, 0x15, 0x04, 0xC7, 0x23, 0xC3,
  0x18, 0x96, 0x05, 0x9A, 0x07, 0x12, 0x80, 0xE2, 0xEB, 0x27, 0xB2, 0x75, 0x09,
  0x83, 0x2C, 0x1A, 0x1B, 0x6E, 0x5A, 0xA0, 0x52, 0x3B, 0xD6, 0xB3, 0x29, 0xE3,
  0x2F, 0x84, 0x53, 0xD1, 0x00, 0xED, 0x20, 0xFC, 0xB1, 0x5B, 0x6A, 0xCB, 0xBE,
  0x39, 0x4A, 0x4C, 0x58, 0xCF, 0xD0, 0xEF, 0xAA, 0xFB, 0x43, 0x4D, 0x33, 0x85,
  0x45, 0xF9, 0x02, 0x7F, 0x50, 0x3C, 0x9F, 0xA8, 0x51, 0xA3, 0x40, 0x8F, 0x92,
  0x9D, 0x38, 0xF5, 0xBC, 0xB6, 0xDA, 0x21, 0x10, 0xFF, 0xF3, 0xD2, 0xCD, 0x0C,
  0x13, 0xEC, 0x5F, 0x97, 0x44, 0x17, 0xC4, 0xA7, 0x7E, 0x3D, 0x64, 0x5D, 0x19,
  0x73, 0x60, 0x81, 0x4F, 0xDC, 0x22, 0x2A, 0x90, 0x88, 0x46, 0xEE, 0xB8, 0x14,
  0xDE, 0x5E, 0x0B, 0xDB, 0xE0, 0x32, 0x3A, 0x0A, 0x49, 0x06, 0x24, 0x5C, 0xC2,
  0xD3, 0xAC, 0x62, 0x91, 0x95, 0xE4, 0x79, 0xE7, 0xC8, 0x37, 0x6D, 0x8D, 0xD5,
  0x4E, 0xA9, 0x6C, 0x56, 0xF4, 0xEA, 0x65, 0x7A, 0xAE, 0x08, 0xBA, 0x78, 0x25,
  0x2E, 0x1C, 0xA6, 0xB4, 0xC6, 0xE8, 0xDD, 0x74, 0x1F, 0x4B, 0xBD, 0x8B, 0x8A,
  0x70, 0x3E, 0xB5, 0x66, 0x48, 0x03, 0xF6, 0x0E, 0x61, 0x35, 0x57, 0xB9, 0x86,
  0xC1, 0x1D, 0x9E, 0xE1, 0xF8, 0x98, 0x11, 0x69, 0xD9, 0x8E, 0x94, 0x9B, 0x1E,
  0x87, 0xE9, 0xCE, 0x55, 0x28, 0xDF, 0x8C, 0xA1, 0x89, 0x0D, 0xBF, 0xE6, 0x42,
  0x68, 0x41, 0x99, 0x2D, 0x0F, 0xB0, 0x54, 0xBB, 0x16
};
```

Once the S-box is located, try to find every function that look at this memory address and you will locate the AES encryption/decryption algorithm.

Comment: Why don't you spend some time describing what you already tried first? It will spare our time and you will get more accurate answers.

Comment: Go learn assembly... there is no other way if you want to reverse a binary program.

Comment: Of course there's a myriad of ways to camouflage the S-Box and only reveal it at runtime.

Comment: Sir thank you for your guideline. I want to say I have successfully identified the S-Box and that was in 7z.dll file not in exe. Now I want to know what should I do to see what key length is used and which type of encryption is used like CBC/ECB etc